# File Move Google Drive API v3 PHP

Tags: php, laravel, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

Using Google API v3 I try to move a file from one folder to another. I am using a wrapper class in Laravel, the file and parent IDs are correct. Developing from the documentation, I have tried code as:

```
public function moveFileFromTo($fileID, $toParentID) {
    $fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ['fields' => '*']);
    $fromParentID = $fromFile->getParents();
    $blankFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
    $this->service->files->update($fileID, $blankFile, [
        "removeParents" => $fromParentID,
        "addParents" => $toParentID
    ]);
}
```

However, this seems to move the file but strips out all the meta data.
I have also tried

```
public function moveFileFromTo($fileID, $toParentID) {
    $fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ['fields' => '*']);
    $fromParentID = $fromFile->getParents();
    $fromFile->setParents($fromParentID);
    $this->service->files->update($fileID, $fromFile);
}
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Google\Service\Exception
{ "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": 
"fieldNotWritable", "message": "The resource body includes fields 
which are not directly writable." } ], "code": 403, "message": "The 
resource body includes fields which are not directly writable." } }
```

I wish to simply move the file and retain all its metadata. From the documentation, it seems either a new empty file is required in update (really weird) or I must somehow strip out the fields of the object used in the second argument ($fromFile) it does not like to be written to (even though I am simply updating the files parents - which is writable).

See also https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/199921300

---

**Problems with Answers so far:**
but grateful for responses

```
$fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ['fields' => 'parents, id']);
```

returns all ~75 attributes a lot of which are not writeable.
Instead of the expected 2 as per PHPStorm debug (note the break is at the statement immediately following the GET request so irrelevant at this point

[image]

using

```
unset($fromFile->shared);
```

still leaves other writable attributes

and indeed the file is not actually shared

[image]

---

**UPDATE TO MY CODING**

```
public function moveFileFromTo($fileID, $toParentID) {
    $fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ["fields" => "id,parents"]);
    $fromFile = $this->getParsedWritableFile($fromFile);
    $fromFile->setParents($toParentID);
    $this->service->files->update($fileID, $fromFile, ['addParents' => $toParentID]);
}
```

getParsedWritableFile is trying to just set writable attributes on a new Google Drive file object:

```
public function getParsedWritableFile($gdrivefile) {
        $gdrivefile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();//comment or delete, just here to check auto complete function names

        $parsedFile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
        //$parsedFile=$gdrivefile;
        // currently only allow these according to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations
        $parsedFile->setName($gdrivefile->getName());//name
        $parsedFile->setMimeType($gdrivefile->getMimeType());//mimeType
        $parsedFile->setDescription($gdrivefile->getDescription());//description
        $parsedFile->setStarred($gdrivefile->getStarred());//starred
        $parsedFile->setTrashed($gdrivefile->getTrashed());//trashed
        $parsedFile->setParents($gdrivefile->getParents());//parents
        $parsedFile->setProperties($gdrivefile->getProperties());//properties  [object]
        $parsedFile->setAppProperties($gdrivefile->getAppProperties());//appProperties [object]
        $parsedFile->setCreatedTime($gdrivefile->getCreatedTime());//createdTime
        $parsedFile->setModifiedTime($gdrivefile->getModifiedTime());//modifiedTime
        $parsedFile->setWritersCanShare($gdrivefile->getWritersCanShare());//writersCanShare
        $parsedFile->setViewedByMeTime($gdrivefile->getViewedByMeTime());//viewedByMeTime
        $parsedFile->setFolderColorRgb($gdrivefile->getFolderColorRgb());//folderColorRgb
        $parsedFile->setOriginalFilename($gdrivefile->getOriginalFilename());//originalFilename
        $parsedFile->setCopyRequiresWriterPermission($gdrivefile->getCopyRequiresWriterPermission());//copyRequiresWriterPermission

        /*complex permissions*/
        /*
        contentHints.thumbnail.image
        contentHints.thumbnail.mimeType
        contentHints.indexableText
         */
        $contenthints=$gdrivefile->getContentHints();//could be null meaning further functions eg getThumbnail cause exception
        if($contenthints){
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getThumbnail()->getImage());
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getThumbnail()->getMimeType());
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getIndexableText());
        }

        /*no function to get indiviual attributes*/
        /*
contentRestrictions[].readOnly
ccontentRestrictions[].reason
         */
        $parsedFile->setContentRestrictions($gdrivefile->getContentRestrictions());

        //</ end>
        return $parsedFile;
    }
```

This is proving a bit successful but this is original meta
[image]

the above code does move it, with seemingly proper meta data, created time and EXIF data is now intact

[image]

Comment: Looks like there are more people experiencing the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/48891303/1702206 
https://laravelquestions.com/2021/09/14/file-move-google-drive-api-v3-php/

Comment: You might want to try copying the file to the new location, then removing the file from the original location. This may preserve the metadata.

Comment: @ajt that seems like that site has just been copying Stackoverflow !!! The question is word for word

Comment: @Datadimension word for word o.0 yup copying stackoverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom function to only include writeable attributes as specified in the Google Documentation:

```
public function getParsedWritableFile($gdrivefile) {
        $gdrivefile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();//comment or delete, just here to check auto complete function names
        $parsedFile = new \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();

        // currently only allow these according to https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource-representations
        $parsedFile->setName($gdrivefile->getName());//name
        $parsedFile->setMimeType($gdrivefile->getMimeType());//mimeType
        $parsedFile->setDescription($gdrivefile->getDescription());//description
        $parsedFile->setStarred($gdrivefile->getStarred());//starred
        $parsedFile->setTrashed($gdrivefile->getTrashed());//trashed
        $parsedFile->setParents($gdrivefile->getParents());//parents
        $parsedFile->setProperties($gdrivefile->getProperties());//properties  [object]
        $parsedFile->setAppProperties($gdrivefile->getAppProperties());//appProperties [object]
        $parsedFile->setCreatedTime($gdrivefile->getCreatedTime());//createdTime
        $parsedFile->setModifiedTime($gdrivefile->getModifiedTime());//modifiedTime
        $parsedFile->setWritersCanShare($gdrivefile->getWritersCanShare());//writersCanShare
        $parsedFile->setViewedByMeTime($gdrivefile->getViewedByMeTime());//viewedByMeTime
        $parsedFile->setFolderColorRgb($gdrivefile->getFolderColorRgb());//folderColorRgb
        $parsedFile->setOriginalFilename($gdrivefile->getOriginalFilename());//originalFilename
        $parsedFile->setCopyRequiresWriterPermission($gdrivefile->getCopyRequiresWriterPermission());//copyRequiresWriterPermission

        /*complex permissions*/
        /*
        contentHints.thumbnail.image
        contentHints.thumbnail.mimeType
        contentHints.indexableText
         */
        $contenthints=$gdrivefile->getContentHints();//could be null meaning further functions eg getThumbnail cause exception
        if($contenthints){
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getThumbnail()->getImage());
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getThumbnail()->getMimeType());
            $parsedFile->setContentHints($contenthints->getIndexableText());
        }

        /*no function to get indiviual attributes*/
        /*
contentRestrictions[].readOnly
ccontentRestrictions[].reason
         */
        $parsedFile->setContentRestrictions($gdrivefile->getContentRestrictions());
        return $parsedFile;
    }
```

and called with

```
public function moveFileFromTo($fileID, $toParentID) {
    $fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ["fields" => "id,parents"]);
    $fromFile = $this->getParsedWritableFile($fromFile);
    $fromFile->setParents($toParentID);
    $this->service->files->update($fileID, $fromFile, ['addParents' => $toParentID]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using [file.update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update) which uses [HTTP PATCH](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PATCH) methodology.  By using a PATCH its going to try to update all of the properties in the file object that you send.

You did a file.get and you included fileds *

```
 $fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ['fields' => '*']);
```

By including `'fields' => '*'` you told the API to return to you all of the properties that the file has.  A  [file resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) has a lot of properties and they are not all writeable.

By sending the file.update method all of the fields you are telling it you want to update everything including some of the properties that you are not allowed to update.  To which the api responds with `fieldNotWritable`

The soultion would be to do the following

```
$fromFile = $this->service->files->get($fileID, ['fields' => 'parents, id']);
```

Which will cause the method to only return the two parameters that you actual need.  The id and the parents parameter.  (TBH you may just need the parents part, I would need to test that.)

```
{
 "id": "1x8-vD-XiA5Spf3qp8x2wltablGF22Lpwup8VtxNY",
 "parents": ["0B1bbSFgVLpoXcVDRFRF8tTkU"
 ]
}
```

You should then be allowed to update the parent and move your file.

Comment: this still returns all 75 attributes (is it a bug ?)

Comment: ['fields' => 'parents, id'] should only return those two properties.

Comment: @DalmTo - thanks for response, but as shown in editted question above, it does not. Please ask whatever info you need and thanks for responses so far

Comment: sounds like a case of works for me because I just tested it again and it works file.

Comment: well thanks for testing but it didnt here what version of the API are you using, (here v2.10.1 on php 7.4.13)

Comment: I am using the google drive api v3.    The php client library version should not change it.

Comment: well to check I have just run composer require google/apiclient:^2.11 according to https://packagist.org/packages/google/apiclient and composer likes it and says Downloading google/apiclient (v2.11.0)
  - Upgrading google/apiclient (v2.10.1 => v2.11.0)

Comment: Yes but you are accessing the Google Drive api.  **google/apiclient** is just the client library for google apis.  where by google drive api is just one of them.   These client libraries are programitcally generated from the discovery doc for the api.  This is not an issue with the api or the client library.   By adding fields parameter you can decide which fields you want returned in the file get. You just need to request only those that are writeable.

Comment: I am just trying to find why we get different results. When I use get it returns all fields regardless !

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do in **laravel** but the problem might be

I have also faced the same problem some time and after searching internet for over  months found nothing and one day Referring to [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource-representations), seen that `shared`
isn't a writable field.

That's it, if you are sharing the File and trying to move the file it wouldn't move. Try to un-share the File and then try to move the File it would be done.

Comment: there are many fields that are not writeable. I do not want to manually write code to strip them in case Google changes its mind or adds other fields, which would break the code

Comment: @Datadimension its only 1 simple logic that if the document is shared the document can't be moved, either delete it or un-share it to move the document. You don't have to check other fields.

Comment: Thanks, but the aim is for using coded API. Simple logic is incorrect here as the file is not shared as per google GUI and I unset this attribute using the API and same error anyway